# How to pass a macro as a value for a key?

Tags: pstricks, key-value

I want to pass a macro to a `showgrid` key. The macro can be redefined later. Its possible values are `top`, `bottom`, `false`, `true`.

The following MWE produces a blank page. How to fix it?

```
\documentclass[border=12pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\def\status{true}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=\status](3,3)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason is the definition of the key. The value of the key isn't expanded and the resulting test fails. You can use the following redefinition:

```
\makeatletter
\define@key[psset]{pstricks}{showgrid}[b]{\expandafter\pst@@showgrid#1\@nil}
\makeatother
```

The expansion above works only once. To expand the value of the key you can use:

```
\makeatletter
\define@key[psset]{pstricks}{showgrid}[b]{\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\pst@@showgrid#1\noexpand\@nil}\x}
\makeatother
```

Here the example:

```
\documentclass[border=12pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\def\status{true}
\makeatletter
\define@key[psset]{pstricks}{showgrid}[b]{\expandafter\pst@@showgrid#1\@nil}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\def\status{true}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=\status](3,3)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This gives `! Undefined control sequence. <recently read> \pst@@showgrid`. Do I have to update something?

Comment: @AhmedMusa: I working with TeX Live 2012 and it works without any problems.

Answer (score 4):

Unlike *pgfkeys*, the *xkeyval* package has no provision for expanding the value of a key at `\setkeys`. However, Marco Daniel's solution is so specific for a particular key as to be inapplicable for other keys, even within pstricks. Here is a general solution, which I have adapted from the development version of the *keyreader* package to suit the existing code of *xkeyval*. The idea is to use pointers to indicate the user's desire to expand (fully or partially) the value of a key.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\makeatletter
\def\XKV@s@tkeys#1#2{%
  \XKV@sp@deflist\XKV@na{#2}%
  \XKV@for@n{#1}\CurrentOption{%
    \XKV@expandvalueasneeded
    \expandafter\XKV@s@tk@ys\CurrentOption==\@nil
  }%
}
\def\XKV@expandvalueasneeded{%
  \begingroup
  \def\reserved@a##1##2\@nil##3{%
    \def\reserved@a####1##1####2####3\@nil{%
      \ifx\@nnil####2\else
        \edef\CurrentOption{##3=####2{##2}}%
      \fi
    }%
    \reserved@a
    \expanded\@iden\expandonce{\unexpanded\expandafter}%
    ##1\@nnil\@nil
  }%
  \def\reserved@b##1=##2=##3\@nil{%
    \if\relax\detokenize{##2}\relax\else
      \reserved@a##2\@nil{##1}%
    \fi
  }%
  \expandafter\reserved@b\CurrentOption==\@nil
  \edef\x{\endgroup\edef\noexpand\CurrentOption
    {\noexpand\unexpanded{\unexpanded\expandafter{\CurrentOption}}}}\x
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\def\status{true}
\def\sstatus{\status}

\newpsstyle{gridstyle}{subgriddiv=2}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=\expandonce{\status}](-1,0)(2,2)
%\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=\expanded{\sstatus}](-1,0)(2,2)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

On this site I have seen people trying to use keys defined as macros. So here is a solution that will accept even macros as keys.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\makeatletter
\def\XKV@g@tkeyname#1=#2\@nil#3{%
  \XKV@ifcmd{#1}\savevalue#3{%
    \XKV@rkvtrue\XKV@sgfalse
  }{%
    \XKV@ifcmd{#1}\gsavevalue#3{%
      \XKV@rkvtrue\XKV@sgtrue
    }{%
      \XKV@rkvfalse\XKV@sgfalse
    }%
  }%
  \expandafter\XKV@ifcmd\expandafter{#3}\xkvexpanded#3{%
    \edef#3{#3}%
  }{%
     \expandafter\XKV@ifcmd\expandafter{#3}\xkvexpandonce#3{%
       \edef#3{\unexpanded\expandafter{#3}}%
     }{}%
  }%
}
\def\XKV@s@tkeys#1#2{%
  \XKV@sp@deflist\XKV@na{#2}%
  \XKV@for@n{#1}\CurrentOption{%
    \begingroup
    \@tempcnta\z@
    \XKV@expandkvasneeded
    \edef\x{\endgroup\edef\noexpand\CurrentOption
      {\noexpand\unexpanded{\unexpanded\expandafter{\CurrentOption}}}}\x
    \expandafter\XKV@s@tk@ys\CurrentOption==\@nil
  }%
}
\def\XKV@expandkvasneeded{%
  \def\reserved@a##1##2\@nil##3{%
    \def\reserved@a####1##1####2####3\@nil{%
      \ifx\@nnil####2\else
        \ifnum\@tempcnta=\z@
          \edef\CurrentOption{####2{##2}=\unexpanded{##3}}%
        \else
          \edef\CurrentOption{##3=####2{##2}}%
        \fi
      \fi
    }%
    \reserved@a
    \xkvexpanded\@iden\xkvexpandonce{\unexpanded\expandafter}##1\@nnil\@nil
  }%
  \def\reserved@b##1=##2=##3\@nil{%
    \ifnum\@tempcnta=\z@
      \reserved@a##1\@nil{##2}%
    \else
      \if\relax\detokenize{##2}\relax\else
        \reserved@a##2\@nil{##1}%
      \fi
    \fi
  }%
  \expandafter\reserved@b\CurrentOption==\@nil
  \ifnum\@tempcnta=\@ne\else
    \@tempcnta\@ne
    \expandafter\XKV@expandkvasneeded
  \fi
}
\let\xkvexpanded\relax
\let\xkvexpandonce\relax
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\def\status{true}
\def\sstatus{\status}
\def\showgrid{showgrid}

\newpsstyle{gridstyle}{subgriddiv=2}
\begin{pspicture}[\xkvexpanded{\showgrid}=\xkvexpandonce{\status}](-1,0)(2,2)
%\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=\xkvexpanded{\sstatus}](-1,0)(2,2)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```