# Unexpected hung latex compilation with property list retrieval

Tags: latex3, debugging, expl3

This is very closely related to [a previous question of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97082/key-values-getting-improperly-passed-through-a-property-list-getter-function).  From the comments to this previous question, I understand that my approach here is completely wrong headed.  So why bother post a question, right?

I'm posting this question because, in my attempts at debugging and creating a work-around, I have what seem like essentially equivalent approaches but I'm getting different behavior when I run the document through LaTeX.

Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-node}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_new:N \g__sunset_plist
\tl_new:N \l__temporary_tl
\NewDocumentCommand{\setattr}{ mm }
    {
        \prop_gput:Nnn \g__sunset_plist {#1} {#2}
    }
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\gettr}{ m }
    {
        \prop_get:Nn \g__sunset_plist { #1 } \l__temporary_tl
    }
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\gettrdebug}{ m }
    {
        \msg_term:x { I've ~ been ~ passed ~ #1}
        \prop_get:NnN \g__sunset_plist { #1 } \l__temporary_tl
        \tl_use:N \l__temporary_tl
    }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\setattr{my_linestyle}{linestyle=dashed,linecolor=blue}
\setattr{my_line}{\psline[linestyle=dashed,linecolor=blue](A)(B)}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(10,10)

    \pnode(0,0){A}
    \pnode(10,10){B}
    \pnode(10,0){C}
    \pnode(0,10){D}


    \gettr{my_line}   %% <-- works as expected
    \psline[\gettr{my_linestyle}](C)(D)  %% <-- not working
    \psline[\gettrdebug{my_linestyle}](C)(D)  %% <-- not working

\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

In this MWE, `\psline[\gettr{....}]...` generates the error:

```
! Package xkeyval Error: `linestyle=dashed,linecolor=blue' undefined in familie
s `,pstricks,pst-node'.

See the xkeyval package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.36     \psline[\gettr{my_linestyle}](
                                       C)(D)  %% <-- not working
```

And as explained to me in my previous approach, this is just wrong headed.  But what's perplexing me is that `\psline[\gettrdebug{...}]...` just hangs.

Aren't these two functions essentially doing the same thing?  Why does one create a recoverable error and the other seem to hang?

Comment: As David says, you've got a quark here. Broadly, unless you know that a property list will contain an item you should use on of the `TF` versions to test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Beware of playing with quarks, they can bite the unwary.  Add `\tracingall` and you see

```
\g__sunset_plist ->\q_prop my_linestyle\q_prop {linestyle=dashed,linecolor=blue
}\q_prop my_line\q_prop {\psline [linestyle=dashed,linecolor=blue](A)(B)}\q_pro
p 

\q_prop ->\q_prop 

\q_prop ->\q_prop 

\q_prop ->\q_prop 

\q_prop ->\q_prop 

\q_prop ->\q_prop 

\q_prop ->\q_prop 

\q_prop ->\q_prop 

\q_prop ->\q_prop 

\q_prop ->\q_prop 

\q_prop ->\q_prop 

\q_prop ->\q_prop 

\q_prop ->\q_prop 

\q_prop ->\q_prop 

\q_prop ->\q_prop 

\q_prop ->\q_prop 

\q_prop ->\q_prop
```

that is you are in an infinite loop expanding a command that expands to itself.

Comment: (Question 1) So did I get in this loop because I made a none expandable function call in my expandable function?  The thing is, even if that is what I did, `\gettrdebug` seems to work fine if not called from inside `\psline[...]`.  (Question 2) why is the infinite loop only occurring when inside `\psline[...]`?

Comment: yes basically it's classic latex fragile command in moving argument error, latex3 provides higher level structures but it can't protect you from all realities of TeX programming.