# How to pass the value of a command for a key (xticklabels and yticklabels of an axis environment for pgfplots)

Tags: pgfplots, labels, key-value

I have a square matrix plot with identical x and y ticks and tick labels, for which I hope to use a pre-defined command to avoid repeating xticklabels and yticklabels with the same value "{A, B, C}" (my actual case has a much longer list; I am just using a simplified example here).

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\def\ticklabels{A, B, C}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
enlargelimits=false,
xtick=data,
ytick=data,
xticklabels=\ticklabels,
yticklabels=\ticklabels]
\addplot [
matrix plot,
mesh/cols=3,
point meta=explicit]
table [meta=C] {
x y C
0 0 0
1 0 1
2 0 2
0 1 3
1 1 4
2 1 5
0 2 6
1 2 7
2 2 8
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I hope to use a simple command to do this as below, but xticklabels and yticklabels values are clearly not passed properly so that only "A, B, C" as a whole is assigned to the first tick, and other ticks become empty.

[image: Result of the above example code]

I guess it is because the command is not expanded before being interpreted. I read [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66355/how-to-pass-a-macro-as-a-value-for-a-key) and tried to use the solution provided there, but could not find how to get it work. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

## New (smart?) answer

The below old answer implements something that is already implemented in `pgfkeys` (and I just forgot about it).

In `pgfkeys` there are handlers to do expansion of the given values, those are `.expand once`, `.expand twice` and `.expanded` (the last one fully expands in `\edef`). You can use those to expand your macro:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\def\ticklabels{A, B, C}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
enlargelimits=false,
xtick=data,
ytick=data,
xticklabels/.expand once=\ticklabels,
yticklabels/.expand once=\ticklabels]
\addplot [
matrix plot,
mesh/cols=3,
point meta=explicit]
table [meta=C] {
x y C
0 0 0
1 0 1
2 0 2
0 1 3
1 1 4
2 1 5
0 2 6
1 2 7
2 2 8
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Output like in the old answer.

---

## Old (stupid) answer

The following defines the keys `xticklabels-exp` and `yticklabels-exp` that'll expand the argument of those keys once and forward the result to `xticklabels` and `yticklabels`. This way you can use macros:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset
  {%
     xticklabels-exp/.code=%
      {%
        \expanded
          {\noexpand\pgfkeysalso{xticklabels={\unexpanded\expandafter{#1}}}}%
      }
    ,yticklabels-exp/.code=%
      {%
        \expanded
          {\noexpand\pgfkeysalso{yticklabels={\unexpanded\expandafter{#1}}}}%
      }
  }

\begin{document}

\def\ticklabels{A, B, C}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
enlargelimits=false,
xtick=data,
ytick=data,
xticklabels-exp=\ticklabels,
yticklabels-exp=\ticklabels]
\addplot [
matrix plot,
mesh/cols=3,
point meta=explicit]
table [meta=C] {
x y C
0 0 0
1 0 1
2 0 2
0 1 3
1 1 4
2 1 5
0 2 6
1 2 7
2 2 8
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Explanation of this answer:

`\pgfkeysalso{<key=val-list>}` is the same as if you used that list in the outer `\pgfkeys`-call but you can use this in the code of your keys.

`\expanded` fully expands its argument (similar but not exactly like `\edef` would, namely macro parameters need no special handling unlike in `\edef`).

`\noexpand` protects the following token from expanding in an expansion context (so in an `\expanded` or `\edef`).

`\unexpanded` is similar to `\noexpand` but takes an argument and protects the entire argument (with removing the one set of braces).

`\expandafter` steps over the following token and first expands the next one. Since `\unexpanded` expands everything until it finds an opening brace (weird given its name...) and so expands the `\expandafter`, which steps over the opening brace and expands the first token in the argument of `\unexpanded` once.

Comment: Many thanks. This does work nicely. Do you mind explaining the new style a bit? I am not familiar with the expansion-related commands and can't fully understand why the combination does the magic.

Comment: @hooklee I tried to give some information on the used macros which should point out how the magic is working. However, I forgot that `pgfkeys` already has this functionality build in... So I've added a new, better answer (inside the above answer).

Comment: Hi Skillmon, the new solution looks so elegant and shows how much I still didn't know about pgfplots! The old solution and the explanation are still very useful for me to understand expand-related commands. \unexpanded does look an oddly defined command given what it does.

Comment: @hooklee it's a primitive, many primitives have some pitfalls that might seem surprising. But the behaviour to search for an opening brace in this way is quite common in TeX, `\expanded` would do the same (expand till it finds a begin-group token), same goes for token register assignments (both `\expanded` and `\unexpanded` are on the implementation level somewhat special token registers), box assignments, etc. Also the new solution isn't `pgfplots` exclusive, that's provided by the underlying `pgfkeys` implementation of Ti*k*Z/`pgf`.

Comment: Thanks for the further explanation. I rarely use TeX native commands and much less pgf these days. Just checked pgf manual, and saw the precise explanation on .expand: "This handler expands hvaluei once (more precisely, it executes an \expandafter command on the first token of hvaluei) and then process the resulting hresulti as if you had written hkeyi=hresulti." It seems ".expanded" is better since I need the final results (if nested all commands should be expanded).

Answer (score 1):

I would probably define a new style that sets both `xticklabels` and `yticklabels` at the same time. In the example below they're set to the same thing, and the list of labels is set as a default value for the key. If you want different lists, replace the two `#1` with your lists, and remove the line with `.default`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
  xyticklabels/.style={
    xticklabels={#1},
    yticklabels={#1}
  },
  xyticklabels/.default={A,B,C} % set the default value for #1
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
enlargelimits=false,
xtick=data,
ytick=data,
xyticklabels  % <--  no value passed to the key, so the default A,B,C is used
]
\addplot [
matrix plot,
mesh/cols=3,
point meta=explicit]
table [meta=C] {
x y C
0 0 0
1 0 1
2 0 2
0 1 3
1 1 4
2 1 5
0 2 6
1 2 7
2 2 8
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
enlargelimits=false,
xtick=data,
ytick=data,
xyticklabels={D,E,F}  % <-- a value passed to the key, so D,E,F is used instead
]
\addplot [
matrix plot,
mesh/cols=3,
point meta=explicit]
table [meta=C] {
x y C
0 0 0
1 0 1
2 0 2
0 1 3
1 1 4
2 1 5
0 2 6
1 2 7
2 2 8
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks. Your code contains a minor error about the default style, "abclabels" should read "xyticklabels". This solution always also solves the problem, I'd like to use a pre-defined command for the value, which does not seem work with your newly defined style.

Comment: @hooklee Oops, sorry about that mistake, will fix.

Comment: Saw you changed the error :-) I just edited my original comment because I found your newly defined style does not work with a pre-defined command, so it seems Skillmon's solution has to be used if a pre-defined command is preferred (which is my case).

Comment: @hooklee No, my thought was that if the purpose was to define the ticklist for plots just once, it wouldn't be necessary to use a macro. But if there are other reasons to prefer a macro then Skillmon's method would be better I guess.

Comment: Yes I have some other reasons to prefer a pre-defined command. Basically, I have a set of such pre-defined commands for different key values, which I want to keep them together so the code looks tidier. And the pre-defined command may also be used elsewhere of the whole document (main text).

Answer (score 0):

The above answers can be combined to have a simpler solution with just one new style.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
     xyticklabels/.code={
        \expanded{
              \noexpand\pgfkeysalso{
                xticklabels={\unexpanded\expandafter{#1}},
                yticklabels={\unexpanded\expandafter{#1}}
              }
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}

\def\ticklabels{A, B, C}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
enlargelimits=false,
xtick=data,
ytick=data,
xyticklabels={\ticklabels}]
\addplot [
matrix plot,
mesh/cols=3,
point meta=explicit]
table [meta=C] {
x y C
0 0 0
1 0 1
2 0 2
0 1 3
1 1 4
2 1 5
0 2 6
1 2 7
2 2 8
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xticklabels from table` to use a table or a file.

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotstableread{
ticks
A
B
C
}\loadedtable
\begin{axis}[
enlargelimits=false,
xtick=data,
ytick=data,
xticklabels from table={\loadedtable}{ticks},
yticklabels from table={\loadedtable}{ticks},
]
\addplot [
matrix plot,
mesh/cols=3,
point meta=explicit]
table [meta=C] {
x y C
0 0 0
1 0 1
2 0 2
0 1 3
1 1 4
2 1 5
0 2 6
1 2 7
2 2 8
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Colored squares with tick labels]

Comment: Thanks. This new solution is interesting. I was not aware of "xticklabels from table".